# rasa ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSignatureError

Tags: python-3.x, jwt, rasa, rasa-x

we are trying to run rasa-x  (0.22.2) on a ubuntu server 18.04 with python 3.6.8 installed. Rasa 1.4.3 itself works fine with all the components. However, we can not get rasa-x to run - it throws this error below. jwt is installed with version 1.7.1. We also reinstalled rasa-x without success. Appreciate any hint how to overcome this. 
Thx, Uli

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasax/community/jwt.py", line 5, in 
    from jwt import InvalidSignatureError
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSignatureError

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04

Python 3.6

I meet the same issue:

At first, I install Py3.5 which is not compatible for RASA so I install Py3.6 and re-link python3 and pip3 in /usr/bin, I can run 'rasa init' and 'rasa shell' smoothly, but when I run 'rasa x', this issue will occur:

scrooge@scrooge-X455LD:~/RASA$ rasa x

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/rasa", line 8, in

```
sys.exit(main())
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa/**main**.py", line 76, in main

```
cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa/cli/x.py", line 291, in rasa_x

```
run_locally(args)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa/cli/x.py", line 379, in run_locally

```
from rasax.community import local  # pytype: disable=import-error
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasax/community/local.py", line 13, in

```
import rasax.community.jwt
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasax/community/jwt.py", line 5, in

```
from jwt import InvalidSignatureError
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSignatureError'

Error in sys.excepthook:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook

```
from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
```

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/**init**.py", line 5, in

```
from apport.report import Report
```

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in

```
import apport.fileutils
```

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in

```
from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
```

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in

```
import apt
```

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/**init**.py", line 23, in

```
import apt_pkg
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/local/bin/rasa", line 8, in

```
sys.exit(main())
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa/**main**.py", line 76, in main

```
cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa/cli/x.py", line 291, in rasa_x

```
run_locally(args)
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasa/cli/x.py", line 379, in run_locally

```
from rasax.community import local  # pytype: disable=import-error
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasax/community/local.py", line 13, in

```
import rasax.community.jwt
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/rasax/community/jwt.py", line 5, in

```
from jwt import InvalidSignatureError
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSignatureError'